# how to remove public from laravel6 url without renaming server.php into index.php

Tags: laravel

want to remove public from my URL without renaming server.php to index.php

tried to solve this problem simply by making a .htaccess file in the root directory with the following code :

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Gave me error 404

Comment: make virtual host

Answer (score 2):

By default the website will be load from public folder. If you want to remove public from your url,copy .htaccess file from public folder to root and replace the code with the following..

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php
```

Comment: mark as helpful...